# Changing global and local variables

Tags: php

basically I am beginner in learning php. I have a question about local and global scopes in php. So I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php 
    $x = 'outside';

function convert(){
    global $x;
    $x = 'inside';
    echo $x;
}

echo $x . '</br>';

convert();
echo $x;
?>
</body>

</html>
```

So, in my function `convert` I declare the variable in global type by `global $x;`, don’t I?
And then, after writing `convert();` and `echo $x;` it returns to me value of inside. So how I can get a value of outside after writing  `convert();`? 
 I thought I rename the global variable after writing `global $x;` and `$x = 'inside';` in my function, but if I don’t write `convert();` I get my 'outside' value. I think I am confused...
Thanks for help, good luck.

Comment: I formatted the question for proper highlighting, however all the surrounding HTML is irrelevant to the question and should probably be removed.

Comment: @user2864740 thanks, but i don’t think HTML tags are preventing the work of php code, aren’t they?

Comment: tldr: questions should only contain *relevant* information.

Comment: @user2864740 html code is a part of creating websites on php, so i think i don t need to delete it.

Comment: The HTML is simply **not relevant** to *the question* which about *scope of PHP variables* which is *unrelated to any HTML interactions* (excepting as the problem might have simply been invalid PHP tags); and yet I concede that others are free to write/leave mediocre unfocused questions. However, as a general rule: SO generally favors focused questions, preferably those that are (or are close to) a SSCCE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

brother, local variable define in the method and its authority is only in that method. But global variable you can use everywhere on that page or class.

in your case, your answer is 
outside
inside
inside
because when you call first $x because of its globally define it prints the **outside**. when you call that function then it displays the function value **inside** and after that is store the value in $x and again when you print $x it display the inside.
thanks in advance hope you understand.

Comment: Ahh, seems i understood. So, firstly, my variable had name 'outside'. My function changes the name of it pn 'inside'. And then, when i call function, the name of the variable is changed. Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer this giving you example by commenting what each does

```
<?php 

// You are assigning outside to the global scope $x
$x = 'outside';
echo $x; // This echo's 'outside'
convert();

function convert(){
    global $x; // You are declaring $x global so its filled with 'outside'
    $x = 'inside'; // You are changing the global var to inside
    echo $x; // this echo's 'inside'
}

echo $x; // This again echo's 'inside' because that was the last thing that got assigned
```

You could just approach this a little different and don't use global at all like so:

```
<?php 

// You are assigning outside to the global scope $x
$x = 'outside';
echo $x; // This echo's 'outside'
$value = convert($x); // Pass the value to the function and get back 'inside' which is loaded into $value

function convert($value){

    $value = 'inside'; // the $value is only valid inside the function
    echo $value; // this echo's 'inside'
    return $value;
}

echo $x; // This again echo's 'outside' because that was the last thing that got assigned to it
echo $value; // This echo^s 'inside' as this was returned from the function
```

Have a look over this and I think all will become clear: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php